# how to use sqlite3_create_function in android using ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, full-text-search, android-sqlite, fts3

Okay, so I successfully was able to build sqlite using android NDK and my code that it used for sqlite3_create_function, but when I try to use it in a cursor query, it says there is no function. I heard somewhere else on Stackoverflow that it is because the Java implementation of SQLite doesn't have the function, but the C one does. How do I counteract this and make it work? Is it better to just recompile sqlite3 from the android sdk with the function or will this not make a difference? Here is the Android.mk file I used.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#####################################################################

#            build sqlite3                                          #

#####################################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sqlite-amalgamation-3071700

LOCAL_MODULE := sqlite3

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sqlite-amalgamation-3071700/sqlite3.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#####################################################################

#            build our code                    #

#####################################################################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/sqlite-amalgamation-3071700

LOCAL_MODULE := fts3-rank

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fts3-rank.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libsqlite3

#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libsqlite3

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#need main function to have executable

#include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

The code I used for fts3-rank is at https://github.com/coolaj86/sqlite3-fts4-rank/blob/master/fts4-rank.c

I am correctly using rank() and not rankfunc() in my query. I also do not have a JNI include in my C code or native method in my Activity because I do not see how that is useful when I am not calling the method in the activity. I just need it within the query. Yes, I did loadLibrary and am not getting that error on the device. There are like no guides on how to do this online so hopefully someone can answer. The purpose is relevance ranking in Android without Lucene (can you even use it in Android?).

Comment: I ended up attempting to use Lucene in my project so an answer for my purposes isn't needed anymore.